# Transferring data USB

Tags: android, usb, ftdi

I am trying to send and receive data over USB, my device, the Acer Iconia A500 has everything needed to connect to the device and everything, that is fine and works properly, but when I try sending and receiving data it doesn't behave as expected. This is my code

```
for( ; ; ) { //this is the main loop for transferring   
    String get = "$getPos";
    byte[] getBytes = get.getBytes();
    conn.bulkTransfer( epOUT, getBytes, getBytes.length, 500 );

    try {
        Thread.sleep( 500 );
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];
        conn.bulkTransfer( epIN, buffer, 4096, 500 );
        StringBuilder byStr = new StringBuilder();

        for( int i = 0; i < buffer.length; i++ ) {
            if( buffer[i] != 0 ) {
                byStr.append( buffer[i] + ", " );
            }
        }

        l( byStr );
    }
    catch( InterruptedException e ) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if( mStop ) {
        mStopped = true;
        return;
    }

    l( "sent " + counter );
    counter++;
    counter = (byte)( counter % 16 );
}
```

Its meant to return an Array of bytes about 80 characters long but it only returns two bytes back which are 1 and 96, if there was a error on the USB devices end it would still return a few more then two. Is my code even close to correct? I based it of the USB to serial article by serverbox.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I was trying to send data over the wrong baud rate.

Here's the code that works. Posting it for everyone who is using FTDI devices and needs help.

```
private Runnable mLoop = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            UsbDevice dev = sDevice;
            if (dev == null)
                return;
            UsbManager usbm = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
            UsbDeviceConnection conn = usbm.openDevice(dev);
            l("Interface Count: " + dev.getInterfaceCount());
            l("Using "
                    + String.format("%04X:%04X", sDevice.getVendorId(),
                            sDevice.getProductId()));

            if (!conn.claimInterface(dev.getInterface(0), true))
                return;

            conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
                                                            // mConnection.controlTransfer(0×40,
                                                            // 0, 1, 0, null, 0,
                                                            // 0);//clear Rx
            conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
            conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x02, 0x0000, 0, null, 0, 0);// flow
                                                                    // control
                                                                    // none
            conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x0034, 0, null, 0, 0);// baudrate
                                                                    // 57600
            conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x04, 0x0008, 0, null, 0, 0);// data bit
                                                                    // 8, parity
                                                                    // none,
                                                                    // stop bit
                                                                    // 1, tx off

            UsbEndpoint epIN = null;
            UsbEndpoint epOUT = null;

            byte counter = 0;

            UsbInterface usbIf = dev.getInterface(0);
            for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
                l("EP: "
                        + String.format("0x%02X", usbIf.getEndpoint(i)
                                .getAddress()));
                if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                    l("Bulk Endpoint");
                    if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                        epIN = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                    else
                        epOUT = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                } else {
                    l("Not Bulk");
                }
            }

            for (;;) {// this is the main loop for transferring
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String get = "$fDump G" + "\n";
                l("Sending: " + get);

                byte[] by = get.getBytes();

                // This is where it sends
                l("out " + conn.bulkTransfer(epOUT, by, by.length, 500));

                // This is where it is meant to receive
                byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

                StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();

                if (conn.bulkTransfer(epIN, buffer, 4096, 500) >= 0) {
                    for (int i = 2; i < 4096; i++) {
                        if (buffer[i] != 0) {
                            str.append((char) buffer[i]);
                        } else {
                            l(str);
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                }
                // this shows the complete string
                l(str);

                if (mStop) {
                    mStopped = true;
                    return;
                }
                l("sent " + counter);
                counter++;
                counter = (byte) (counter % 16);
            }
        }
    };
```

Comment: No problem. Been a while since I did this.

Comment: Can you include your import statements?