# declaring USB interface between android terminal and embedded linux card

Tags: android, linux, embedded, usb

I hope my question will not be strange or something like that but I started a project concerning dialog between an android terminal (currently a Samsung galaxy S2 but that may change) and an embedded-Linux based card (armadeus apf51-dev but maybe a raspberry pi in the future). Actually, I have an application on the android terminal that display the speed send by the Linux-embedded card via wireless connexion. The main objective is to change this wifi connexion by an USB connexion. My principal problem is to implement the android side of the pipe. I found this answer by FabianCook ( [Transferring data USB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10429615/transferring-data-usb?lq=1) ) :

```
UsbDevice dev = sDevice;
        if (dev == null)
            return;
        UsbManager usbm = (UsbManager) getSystemService(USB_SERVICE);
        UsbDeviceConnection conn = usbm.openDevice(dev);
        l("Interface Count: " + dev.getInterfaceCount());
        l("Using "
                + String.format("%04X:%04X", sDevice.getVendorId(),
                        sDevice.getProductId()));

        if (!conn.claimInterface(dev.getInterface(0), true))
            return;

        conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 0, 0, null, 0, 0);// reset
                                                        // mConnection.controlTransfer(0×40,
                                                        // 0, 1, 0, null, 0,
                                                        // 0);//clear Rx
        conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0, 2, 0, null, 0, 0);// clear Tx
        conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x02, 0x0000, 0, null, 0, 0);// flow
                                                                // control
                                                                // none
        conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x03, 0x0034, 0, null, 0, 0);// baudrate
                                                                // 57600
        conn.controlTransfer(0x40, 0x04, 0x0008, 0, null, 0, 0);// data bit
                                                                // 8, parity
                                                                // none,
                                                                // stop bit
                                                                // 1, tx off

        UsbEndpoint epIN = null;
        UsbEndpoint epOUT = null;

        byte counter = 0;

        UsbInterface usbIf = dev.getInterface(0);
        for (int i = 0; i < usbIf.getEndpointCount(); i++) {
            l("EP: "
                    + String.format("0x%02X", usbIf.getEndpoint(i)
                            .getAddress()));
            if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getType() == UsbConstants.USB_ENDPOINT_XFER_BULK) {
                l("Bulk Endpoint");
                if (usbIf.getEndpoint(i).getDirection() == UsbConstants.USB_DIR_IN)
                    epIN = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
                else
                    epOUT = usbIf.getEndpoint(i);
            } else {
                l("Not Bulk");
            }
        }
```

This is very helpful but I don't understand what is the "sDevice" variable (line 1). I suppose it's an UsbDevice class instance but I don't know how this variable is instantiated. Maybe someone can indicate me the good way ?

Comment: Which will be the USB host, the external board or the Android phone?

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like `sDevice` may have been assigned somewhere else to be made available here, but the original assignment isn't in the sample code in the original thread - I'm not sure where that would have been instantiated but it should simply represent some connected device as the `UsbDevice` object.

`sDevice` would have originated from the `UsbManager` where you can get a list of connected devices with the `getDeviceList()` function

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/usb/UsbManager.html#getDeviceList()